# Idiomatic letterpress cheater

Tags: clojure

I need some guidance on making the following code more idiomatic:

```
(ns cheaterpress.algorithm
  (:use [clojure.string :only [split lower-case]])
  (:use [clojure.test]))

(def words (split (slurp "words") #"\s"))

(defn string-to-letter-hash [string]
  (loop [letters (seq string) letter-hash {}]
    (if (empty? letters)
      letter-hash
      (let [letter (first letters) letter-freq (get letter-hash letter 0)]
        (recur (rest letters) (assoc letter-hash letter (inc letter-freq)))))))

(defn can-play [word letters index]
  (loop [letters letters index index]
    (if (and (= (inc index) (count word)) (not (= 1 (count word))))
      true
      (let [letter (get word index) frequency (get letters letter 0)]
        (when (not (= 0 frequency))
          (recur (assoc letters letter (dec frequency)) (inc index)))))))

(println 
  (time
    (count (doall (filter #(can-play % (string-to-letter-hash "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz") 0) (map lower-case words))))))
```

`string-to-letter-hash` takes a string and returns a map with the letter frequencies, e.g.:

```
(string-to-letter-hash "hello")
;=> {\h 1 \e 1 \l 2 \o 1}
```

`can-play` takes a letter frequency hash and a word, and then it finds out if it can make the word from the letters in the hash map. If it can, it returns true, otherwise, nil.

```
(can-play "hello" {\h 1 \e 1 \l 2 \o 1} 0)
;=> true
(can-play "lol" {\h 1 \e 1 \l 2 \o 1} 0)
;=> true
(can-play "hello world" {\h 1 \e 1 \l 2 \o 1} 0)
;=> nil
```

The last bit of code in my script basically gets all the words in a file and finds which of them can be played according to the `can-play` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is a standard library function: frequences :)

```
user> (doc frequencies)
-------------------------
clojure.core/frequencies
([coll])
  Returns a map from distinct items in coll to the number of times
  they appear.
```

Since in Clojure many many types can be converted to sequences, frequencies will work on many types, including strings. In Clojure you can get an amazing amount of work done simply by using the sequence library. So your `string-to-letter-hash` is actually just an example of `frequences`.

For your `can-play`: the same type of thinking applies. Try to resist your first impulse of writing a loop. The Clojure library functions will almost always do the job - the thing that requires training is knowing the library well enough to find a good way to compose the functions.

```
(defn can-play? [word freqs]
  (every? #(>= % 0) (vals (merge-with - freqs (frequencies word)))))
```

(updated to comment version: https://gist.github.com/4105644)

Comment: What about the case `(every? (complement nil?) (map (frequencies "helloworld") "hellohellohello"))`? This will return true, but the word cannot be formed.

Comment: Also the behavior of: `(every? freqs word)` is equivalent to what you described, yeah? http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/every_q

Comment: I figured it out with multiple letters and frequencies I believe! https://gist.github.com/4105644

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation with recursion over the remaining letters and letter set:

```
(defn can-play [word available]
  (loop [[s & stem] (clojure.string/replace word #"\W" "") available available]
    (or (nil? s) ;; no more letters to check
      (and (pos? (available s 0)) ;; first letter must be in letterbox...
           ;; ...and the rest of the word must be playable after removing one
           ;; first instance of the first letter from the box
           (recur stem (update-in available [s] dec))))))
```